# IEEE 1451 and SensorML

Tags: web-services, sensors, ieee

I am working on IEEE 1451 standard and SensorML. Recently, I read a paper about STWS: unified web service for IEEE 1451, and I don't know what is the difference between this and SensorML? and what is the difference between this and web enablement of sensorML?